# A very simple question about arrays

Tags: php, arrays

If myFunction returns an array, is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
$result = myFunction($parameters);
$result = $result[4];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP does not support array dereferencing in this way, i.e. this is invalid:

```
$result = myFunction($parameters)[4];
```

Some options, none of which are particularly elegant or readable:

```
list(,,,,$result) = myFunction($parameters); // ignore first 3
$result = array_pop( array_slice( myFunction($parameters), 4, 1 ) ); // grab 4th element
```

Comment: In a upcoming release, PHP will support this. The patch has been committed to trunk I believe, it just hasn't made it into a release.

Comment: @alecgorge: Like PHP6? I'm sorry, but unless you can provide an actual php.net link (i.e.: a valid reference) to that information, I can't believe this. :) I mean, we're talking about a change to the parser, and these usually don't make it to release very often.

Comment: Well PHP6 will never exist, but that is a different matter. It will probably be in PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5 or whatever they are going to call it. I don't know why it isn't there yet. Here is the thread on the list: http://markmail.org/message/unplu5x3gjjjydwz#query:+page:1+mid:affsjxr5nl2uxoe4+state:results

Comment: @alecgorge: The actual link you should point to is [this one](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing). However, this is a proposal that has been accepted, but it doesn't mean anything since there aren't anything version number attached to it. :S

Comment: Felipe said he committed it. Here is the commit: http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=300266 . It is also listed under implemented on http://wiki.php.net/rfc

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction ($params, $index = null ) {
  ...
  if ( $index !== null ) return $result [ $index ];
  else return $result;
}

...

$indexed_result = myFunction ( $parameters, 4 );
```

Comment: +1 Since it's a user-defined function, OP has control to add a $index parameter for that purpose. Good catch.